# Receiving HTTP Error 404: Not Found, during image to text conversion

Tags: python, excel, machine-learning, ocr, http-error

I am receiving **HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found error** while implementing easyOCR on image URLs from an excel spreadsheet. The idea is to iterate through every URL in the excel file and create an output excel file with extracted text.

The input file looks like this, [input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxEVs.png)

Apart from iterrows(), I have also used range(len()) and faced the same problem. Kindly advise on fixing this issue. Thanks in advance!

```
def modelling(url):
  reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
  bounds = reader.readtext(url, detail = 0)
  return bounds

new_col = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  img = row['url']
  col = modelling(img)
  new_col.append(col)

df['new_col'] = new_col
filename = "Output_Data.xlsx"
df.to_excel(filename)
print("Data frame is written to Excel file successfully.")
```

The error logs are stated as below.

```
<ipython-input-10-013fb5c72447> in modelling(url)
      1 def modelling(url):
      2   reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
----> 3   bounds = reader.readtext(url, detail = 0)
      4   return bounds

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/easyocr/easyocr.py in readtext(self, image, decoder, beamWidth, batch_size, workers, allowlist, blocklist, detail, paragraph, min_size, contrast_ths, adjust_contrast, filter_ths, text_threshold, low_text, link_threshold, canvas_size, mag_ratio, slope_ths, ycenter_ths, height_ths, width_ths, add_margin)
    345         image: file path or numpy-array or a byte stream object
    346         '''
--> 347         img, img_cv_grey = reformat_input(image)
    348 
    349         horizontal_list, free_list = self.detect(img, min_size, text_threshold,\

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/easyocr/utils.py in reformat_input(image)
    645     if type(image) == str:
    646         if image.startswith('http://') or image.startswith('https://'):
--> 647             tmp, _ = urlretrieve(image , reporthook=printProgressBar(prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete', length = 50))
    648             img_cv_grey = cv2.imread(tmp, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    649             os.remove(tmp)

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    246     url_type, path = splittype(url)
    247 
--> 248     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    249         headers = fp.info()
    250 

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 532             response = meth(req, response)
    533 
    534         return response

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    641             response = self.parent.error(
--> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    643 
    644         return response

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    568         if http_err:
    569             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 570             return self._call_chain(*args)
    571 
    572 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502         for handler in handlers:
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:
    506                 return result

/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    651 
    652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `try` and `except` for handling the error and preventing them from breaking your program. Do something like this

```py
try:
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
    bounds = reader.readtext(url, detail = 0)
    return bounds
except:
    #error raised
    #do something else
```